# Kivy. Setting color for frontend and backend in one variable

Tags: kivy

I'm looking for a way to set colors for frontend and backend in one place. Let it be a dictionary like in a code below. When I start the program I wan't it to set the colors for `kv` string without need it to hardcode it in this string as `#:set main_bcolor hex('#f4f8fb')`. If this is possible it would be very useful and clean as I don't need to repeat color definitions.

***CODE***

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1280')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '720')

from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder


colors = {
    'main_bcolor' : get_color_from_hex('#f4f8fb'),
    'active_bcolor': get_color_from_hex('#cde2fc')
}

kv = """

<Dir@BoxLayout>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0, 0, 1)  if main_bcolor is None else main_bcolor
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
Dir:

"""

class RemoteDir(App):
    def build(self):

        for color in colors.items():
            print('Setting color for frontend and backend', color[0], color[1])

        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RemoteDir().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A convenient way to do that is to create a `DictProperty` that can be referenced in the 'kv':

```
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import DictProperty

Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1280')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '720')

from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

kv = """
<Dir@BoxLayout>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: app.colors['main_bcolor']
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
Dir:
"""

class RemoteDir(App):
    colors = DictProperty({
        'main_bcolor' : get_color_from_hex('#f4f8fb'),
        'active_bcolor': get_color_from_hex('#cde2fc')
    })

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RemoteDir().run()
```